# Previous build stuck on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

I have an odd thing happening, if I test my app on my device it's running as if it's the last build, not the current one.  The simulator works fine.  Deleting the app then running it post build from Xcode shows the icon with a notification symbol, notifications have since been entirely removed.  Also the logic flaw in the previous build is there.

I've cleaned the project etc, rebooted the device.  No luck, any thoughts?

Comment: did you tried deleting the app and reinstalling it ??

Comment: Yep, still no joy.  It's really strange.

Comment: I've tried cleaning, deleting derived path content etc too.  Wondering if I've set different builds for different platforms by mistake?

Comment: Check trash etc once i was facing the same problem so When i opened the trash there was a replica of 6.1 folder...

Comment: Try changing the app bundle ID (in the target settings).  What happens when you clean the project, change that, and then build to the device?

Comment: That worked Wolflink, add as an answer and I'll make it.  Cheers for the help everyone :)